# BeanShell error message in android studio

Tags: java, android, beanshell

I am a beginner in java , I was making a simple calculator app in [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) using [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) . When I run the project , It works fine only on my emulator . For real devices , this app can be installed only . When I try to run , the app crashes showing "`Unfortunately 'X' app has been stopped`.

My code is too simple :

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
String equation = "2+3*9"; // I gave user to input his own via editText, 
                           // Lets think for a simple case
Object answer1 = interpreter.eval(equation);
String answer = answer1.toString();
```

Log :

EVENT LOG : http://pastebin.com/JwcuV0ch

GRADLE BUILD MESSAGE : http://pastebin.com/8cDXp0N5

1)Would you please explain why this error occurs?

2)From build message, I am pasting some lines:

```
Error:(bsh.Interpreter$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably    produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
```

I got the line `compiler that did not target the mordern .class file format`
repeatedly in my build message . So please let me know how can I recompile `BeanShell` ?

[ P.S. :
In [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) I have wrote the same code to evalute value from a string .

```
import bsh.Interpreter;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
             Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
             String equation = "2+3*9"; // I gave user to input his own via editText in android, 
                           // Lets think for a simple case
              String answer = interpreter.eval(equation);
              System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Everything was fine there , Now it is strange to me why the same code create problem in `Android Studio` ]

Answer (score 1):

*Interpreter.eval()* returns an *Object*, not a *String*.
So you most likely encounter a problem in casting from an *Integer* to a *String*:

> Target exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
>   java.lang.Integer to java.lang.String

Try to cast the Integer return value to a String and it should work:

```
String answer = String.valueOf(interpreter.eval(equation));
```